# When hovering over link display image next to link

Tags: html, css

Normally, i want the red arrow to not display.  But when a user hovers their mouse over "My Cart (0)"  I want the red arrow to display.  how can u do this with html/css?

[image]

Comment: And what mark-up would you be using? Is the image an `img`, a `background-image`, generated content..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ePf3A/

What this does is change the width of the image to show/hide the arrow.

```
.cart {
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2o7H.png);
  width: 100px;
  height: 45px;
  display: block;
}
.cart:hover {
  width: 150px;
}
​
```

The other option is use a different image and change between then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little CSS trick to make an arrow from a div using it's borders, then show it when a user `:hover` your cart. Hover the black rectangle in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/fWZ84/).